# Another MVC mapping not found

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, servlets, mapping

I've set up some spring MVC configurations before but this time it seems that I'm missing something. Here comes the configuration :

**web.xml :**

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>    

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml :**

```xml
<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan base-package="mypackage.controller" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="/gupld">uploadController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

**ManController.java :**

```java
package mypackage.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public ModelAndView welcome() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("_index");
        return mav;
    }
}
```

And when I call `http://127.0.0.1:8080/mycontext/test/` I get:

```
http-8080-1 INFO  2012-12-26 09:27:24,799 SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/test] onto handler 'mainController'
http-8080-1 WARN  2012-12-26 09:27:24,887 PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/mycontext/test/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

Any idea?

Comment: what is your calling jsp ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using url-pattern as `/test/*` to load `dispatcher` servlet.

But you are sending `/mycontext/test/` which is not mapping to provided url.

Try to use this,

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*/test</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Or Use This

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I get a : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: <url-pattern> */test invalid in filter mapping

Comment: Ok problem solved. The embedded tomcat in eclipse seemed to be slow on taking spring configuration changes into account..  even though I manually clean its working directories, republished, etc. several times. Now it works like a charm without changing a line...